# DataContextを使う際のthisとx:Name指定の違いについて

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

this.DataContextで値を反映する場合と
 btnA.DataContextで値を反映する場合の違いは何でしょうか。

スレッドでbtnA,btnBを同時に実行した場合thisを使った場合は画面がちらつきました。
詳しい方がいましたら教えて頂けると助かります。

XAML

```
    <Grid>
    <Button x:Name="btnA" Content="{Binding ButtonContentA}" Click="Button_ClickA"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnB" Content="{Binding ButtonContentB}" Click="Button_ClickB"/>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
void Worker_ProgressChangedA(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    //スレッドの画面再描画でthisを使うと画面がちらつく
    //this.DataContext = new { ButtonContentA =  e.ProgressPercentage };
    btnA.DataContext = new { ButtonContentA = e.ProgressPercentage };
    }

void Worker_ProgressChangedB(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {    
    //this.DataContext = new { ButtonContentB =  e.ProgressPercentage };
    btnA.DataContext = new { ButtonContentB = e.ProgressPercentage };
    }
```

Comment: 単に影響範囲が大きいため処理がもたついているだけではないでしょうか。なお`DataContext`自体ではなくプロパティの値を変更するようにすべきです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。xaml側には基本的にBindingでアクセスするべきだと思ってました。プロパティで変更してみます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataContext自体を逐次変更するのは正しいスタイルとは言えません。
this.DataContext自体を変更すると下位のコントロールすべてに変更通知が飛びます。

データバインドを使う場合、DataContextにはINotifyPropertyChangedを実装したオブジェクトを代入し使いまわしましょう。データバインドしたコントロールはプロパティの変更を常に監視しています。変更通知を投げればコントロール側も変更を追従します。

```
// NotificationObjectは実装を探して見てください。ここでは割愛します。
public class SamplePresenter : NotificationObject
{
    public int ButtonContentA
    {
        get { return _ButtonContentA; }
        set
        {
            if (_ButtonContentA != value)
            {
                _ButtonContentA = value;
                // ここでPropertyChangedEventArgs("ButtonContentA")が
                // 通知されると思ってください
                RaisePropertyChanged("ButtonContentA");
            }
        }
    }
    private int _ButtonContentA;
}

public partial class SampleWindow : Window
{
    // 少し手抜きですが以下のようにバインドされていたとして
    public SampleWindow() {
        this.DataContext = Presenter = new SamplePresenter();
    }
    public SamplePresenter Presenter { get; set; }

    void Worker_ProgressChangedA(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //スレッドからPresenterの値を更新します
        this.Presenter.ButtonContentA = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
}
```

Comment: ソースの提示までありがとうございます。
INotifyPropertyChangedについて勉強させて頂きます。

Answer (score 2):

DataBindingsとDataContextの基本的な利用方法に関しては以下のエントリーにざっくりまとめているので、目を通して参考にしていただければ幸いです。

> サンプルコードを見ながら理解するMVVMの基礎的な実装 - Neutral Scent
>   http://d.hatena.ne.jp/kaorun/20141202/1417532472

すでにpgrhoさんやharu666さんが述べられているように、DataContextはデータ更新のたびに逐一変更するべきではありません。this.DataContextを変更してしまうと、対象となるウインドウもしくはフォーム全体の再描画が都度走ってしまうためフリッカが起きていると思われます。

単に値を代入・表示したいだけであれば、WinForms時代のように、btnA.Content/btnB.Contentに直接変更値を代入してしまうのも手ですが、DataBindingを利用してよりモダンにMVVM的な実装を目指すのであれば、INotifyPropertyChangedインターフェイスを継承したクラス(ViewModel)を実装し、このクラスで生成したデータをこのウインドウ(View)で表示するよ、とDataContextに割り当て、そのクラスの変更をView側に通知してやるのが今風である、というイメージです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
Bindingの考え方がひとつ深まりました。
WPFのよいソースがないので助かります。